# Creating a 'select list which support dynamic actions' using the 'on change' dynamic action of another select list in Oracle APEX 5.1

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I am developing an application using Oracle APEX 5.1

I have a requirement, where, based on the value selected in the first select list, a second select list should be populated. Based on second list value, a third list should be populated and so on till we reach the lowest level in the hierarchy.So the no.of select lists will be equal to the no.of levels in the hierarchy.

Also, these select list should be dynamic select lists which supports SQL query.

Since the no.of levels in the hierarchy are large, I think we need to create the select lists for different levels dynamically. I couldn't find any helping documents regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of select lists depends on the values chosen about it you could use the dynamic pl/sql region type in APEX to draw the select boxes by using the apex_item.select_list function.

See API documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E71588_01/AEAPI/APEX_ITEM.htm#AEAPI192

I am currently doing this at work to submit reports of varying parameters where each report could have multiple select list fields.

Comment: Thanks for your help.When I  paste the sample code in the apex docs,'SELECT APEX_ITEM.SELECT_LIST_FROM_QUERY(3,job,'SELECT DISTINCT job FROM emp')job 
FROM emp' (converted to pl/sql form), inside the pl/sql code box  of the pl/sql dynamic content region and execute, its is not working.nothing is getting rendererd when i run the page. Maybe I am going wrong somewhere.Can you please post a sample code for this.

Comment: Did you do HTP.p in the plsql for the dynamic region?

Comment: Thanks Arijit, that was the problem.When I added HTP.p in my pl/sql code ,the list got rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm wrong, all you have to do is to set Select List item's **Cascading LOV Parent Item(s)** property.

Apex help says:

> Enter page or application items that trigger the refresh of this list
>   of values. For multiple items, separate each item name with a comma.
>   You can type in the name or pick from the list of available items. If
>   you pick from the list, and there is already text entered, then a
>   comma is placed at the end of the existing text, followed by the item
>   name returned from the list.
>
> This list of values is refreshed whenever the value of any of the
>   specified items are changed on this page.
>
> You should use the page item(s) specified in this attribute within the
>   where clause of this list of values SQL Query to restrict the values
>   returned.
>
> For example, if you have page items for Car Make and Model, you could
>   specify Car Make as the Cascading LOV Parent Item within the List of
>   Values definition for Model, and use Car Make within the where clause
>   for that list of values. Then whenever Car Make is changed, the LOV
>   for Model is refreshed, and the list only displays values for the
>   currently selected Car Make.

Comment: Yeah, but here I don't know how many 'select list' page items should be created since I have to traverse the entire hierarchy of the hierarchical data .The no.of levels depends(varies with)  on the value selected from the previous select lists.